# How to set %20 for space in url attributes?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting, jsonp, json

i am developing a android application for some data's send to server side through GPRS and SMS(via sms gateway).Now i am trying to send data through GPRS first,actually our sms gateway service provider has given the format that how to send data to the gateway.the format is having the white spaces in between the datas.In this case when i am going to send data like this format,url encodes the spaces as "+" symbol, but i want to encode the space like "%20", because url not supported the way,when i am going to give "%20" in url directly instead of "+", its working fine,otherwise it will goes to error page.So how to change this?what i want to do?please help me...? thanks in advance.

Source code:

```
function AttForm()
{
    var att=$('#attnce').val();
    var uname=window.localStorage.getItem('uname');
    if(att==0){
        alert("Select Attendance");
        return false;
    }

    var message="MRCC";
    message += " "+"VIPATT";
    message += " "+uname;
    message += " "+att;    

    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    if(states[networkState]==states[Connection.NONE]){
        window.plugins.sms.send(09192939495,message,function(){ 
           alert('Message sent successfully');  
        },
        function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    }
    else{           
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://aaa.com/test/webservice.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{type:'VIPATT',message:message},
            dataType:'jsonp',
            jsonp:'callback',
            success:successData,
            error:function(){
                alert("error")
            }
        });
        function successData(data){
            var response=data.message;
            alert(response);
            $('#att').hide();
            $('#main_menu').delay(500).fadeIn(1000)
        }
    }

}
```

url goes like this:

```
http://aaa.com/test/webservice.php?callback=jQuery16006898061116226017_1343803442450&type=VIPATT&message=MRCC+VIPATT+RSA+2&_=1343803455743:1
```

In the above url you can see the + symbol in between the attributes.but i want %20 instead of the + symbol.how to get this?

Comment: Do you need help with the SMS plugin or with the jQuery ajax?

Comment: `+` is a standard for URLs which should be handled correctly. And if you are using `POST` how are you getting a URL at all?

Comment: Even tried with GET method also,that is taking + symbol only.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use a URL encoding function. Haven't done it myself but found an article that might help http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp